# Ошибка миграции laravel 1215

Tags: laravel, миграция

Я делаю миграции и у меня ошибка: * SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `contacts` add constraint `contacts_service_id_foreign` foreign key (`service_id`) references `services` (`id`) on delete cascade)*

Вот миграция:

```
`class CreateContactsTable extends Migration{
public function up()
{
    // Список контактов
    Schema::create('contacts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->integer('service_id')->comment('Ссылка на сервис');
        $table->integer('contact_type_id')->comment('Тип контакта');
        $table->string('value')->comment('Значение контакта (номер телефона, email, имя, etc.)');
        $table->timestampsTz();

        $table->foreign('service_id')
            ->references('id')->on('services')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('contact_type_id')
            ->references('id')->on('contact_types')
            ->onDelete('restrict');
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('contacts');
}
```

}`

Я понимаю, что у меня может быть порядок создания foreign нарушен?

Comment: Как выглядит таблица services?

Comment: @YaroslavMolchan `{
     Schema::create('services', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->id();
      $table->string('name')->unique()->comment('Идентификатор сервиса для передачи через API');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
        DB::table('services')->insert(['name' => "sms_sender_1"]);
        DB::table('services')->insert(['name' => "blacklist"]);
        DB::table('services')->insert(['name' => "alert_list"]);
        DB::table('services')->insert(['name' => "partners"]);
    }
`
Надеюсь так будет понятно.

Answer (score 0):

У вас реляция ссылается на [PK](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.html#method_id) другой таблицы, а в `Laravel` уже пару версий PK это `unsignedBigInteger`, так что в вашем случае нужно заменить колонку:

```
$table->integer('service_id')->comment('Ссылка на сервис');
```

На:

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('service_id')->comment('Ссылка на сервис');
```

Comment: Итак все значения integer заменить?

Comment: Не все, я уже указал какое нужно заменить.

Comment: Скорее всего потом будет ошибка с contact_type_id, там так же сделать unsignedBigInteger